# SQL Server adding linked server using alias name

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, linked-server, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to add my RDS SQL server database as a linked server to my on-premises database.
The RDS is not publically accessible and is only accessible via ssh.

Below are the steps I tried:

1. I created a ssh tunnel to an aws ec2 instance and mapped the database to be accessible on my server 127.0.0.1:3333. This is the command I used:
   ssh -N -L 3333:{dbname}.c06bf1v8sxgd.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:1433 ec2-user@{instance ip} -i C:\path\to\pem.pem
2. I then created an alias name for the database connection so I can reference it easily as seen in the image below
   [image: alias name for db]
3. I tried using the above alias to create a linked server like this
   [image]
   or
   [image]
   and some many other configuration combinations
   but I'm getting the below error [image: error]

I can connect to the database using the alias without any issue as seen in the screenshot below[image: conn using alias]

Can anyone help me figure out how to add this database as a linked server successfully?

Comment: does it work if you put non-aliased server ip into the linked server "thing"

Comment: sqlcmd -S<SQLServer> -UxXx -PddDD

Comment: Can you ping via the tunnel? The syntax for `ssh` doesn't look correct: `-L 3333:.c06bf1v8sxgd` has an extra `.` and the `usern@` needs a hostname

Comment: fixed the command - I had the dbname and username placeholder wrapped in < and > and it didn't show

The ssh tunned definitely works because connecting the database using the alias works. It only fails when adding it as a linked server